# Oracle - Find matched records with a different value for one field

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Suppose I have the following table in my Oracle DB:

```
Col1:       Col2: ...   Coln:
1           a     ...   1
1           a     ...   1
1           b     ...   1
1           b     ...   1
1           c     ...   1
1           a     ...   1
2           d     ...   1
2           d     ...   1
2           d     ...   1
3           e     ...   1
3           f     ...   1
3           e     ...   1
3           e     ...   1
4           g     ...   1
4           g     ...   1
```

And, what I want to get is a distinct list of records where, for `Col1`, `Col2` is different - Ignoring any times that `Col2` matches for all of `Col1`.

So, in this example I would like to get the result set:

```
Col1:       Col2:
1           a    
1           b     
1           c    
3           e    
3           f
```

Now, I figured out how to do this using a query that feels fairly complex for the question at hand:

```
With MyData as
(
   SELECT b.Col1, b.Col2, count(b.Col2) over(Partition By b.Col1) as cnt from 
   (
    Select distinct a.Col1, a.Col2 from MyTable a 
   ) b
)

select Col1, Col2
from MyData
where cnt > 1
order by Col1
```

What I'm wondering is what is a nicer way to do this - I didn't manage to do this using `GROUP BY` & `HAVING` and probably think this could maybe be done using a self-join... This is more of a quetion to see / learn new ways to get a result in a nicer (and perhaps more efficient) query.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
( SELECT 1 FROM table1 t2
  WHERE t1.col2 <> t2.col2
    AND t1.col1 = t2.col1
) 
order by 1,2
```

demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ce10/12


 **----- EDIT -------**

Yes, there are other ways to do this:

```
SELECT distinct col1, col2
FROM table1 t1
WHERE col2 <> ANY (
  SELECT col2 FROM table1 t2
  WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1
) 
order by 1,2;

SELECT distinct col1, col2
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT col2 = ALL (
  SELECT col2 FROM table1 t2
  WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1
) 
order by 1,2
;

SELECT distinct t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 <> t2.col2 
order by 1, 2
;


SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2
HAVING COUNT( distinct t2.col2 ) > 1
order by 1, 2
;


SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM 
table1 t1
JOIN (
  SELECT col1
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY col1
  HAVING COUNT( distinct col2 ) > 1
) t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2
ORDER BY t1.col1, t1.col2
;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ce10/33

Try them all, I really don't know how they will perform on your data.
However, creating a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX name ON table1( col1, col2 )
```

will most likely speed up all of these queries.

Comment: That works!! - Thank you!!! Just for my education, would this be more efficient than the way I wrote my query? Also, since this is just for me to learn, could you think of any other ways to do this?? - I'm just curious to see what is available to increase my SQL prowess :)

Comment: I am glad I could help. I appended some examples hot to do this in other ways - just for learning purposes.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!!! - This gives me a lot to learn from (which is exactly what I asked for!!!) - THANK YOU SOO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that uses aggregation and an analytic function:

```
with t as (
      select col1, col2,
             count(*) over (partition by col1) as cnt
      from table1
      group by col1, col2
     )
select col1, col2
from t
where cnt > 1;
```

What I would like to do is:

```
  select col1, col2,
         count(*) over (partition by col1) as cnt
  from table1
  group by col1, col2
  having count(*) over (partition by col1) > 1;
```

However, this is not valid SQL because the analytic functions are not allowed in the `having` clause.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this unfortunately doesn't work since the `count` will also count repeated records with the same value, so it will count even non-distinct values for `Col2` :(

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?? Unfortunately, I will tell you ahead of time, I will be marking Kordirko as the correct answer since his was the first solution given that works, but if you would be willing to even just help point me in the right direction for learning purposes, I would GREATLY appreciate it!!!!!